# firebase authentication with facebook

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I tried my level best before asking here.

I am trying to implement facebook authentication with ngcordova auth by following this post [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/03/sign-into-firebase-with-facebook-using-ionic-framework/)

I am using Firebase Firebase v3.6.4 and angularfire in ionic 1.

```
$cordovaOauth.facebook("222222222222", ["email"])
              .then(function (result) {
                var credentials = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.access_token);
                ToastFac.showMsgToUser("Authentication failed:"+result.access_token);
                return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credentials);
              })
              .then(function (firebaseUser) {
                  ToastFac.showMsgToUser("Signed in as:"+ firebaseUser.uid);
                console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                  ToastFac.showMsgToUser("Authentication failed:"+ error);
                console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
              });
```

while trying with above code , I got the facebook login screen and access token but ending up with below error while running in device & emulator. [image]

I have added package name from config xml and SHA1 certificate by generating it from

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "PATH\.android\debug.keystore"
```

I am not sure what else I am missing. Could you please advise here.

Comment: Did you set any limitation on your browser API key? If so, you need to go to the cloud console and remove those.

Comment: Nothing as such.

Comment: Well, that is the typical error when you set "Key restriction" on your browser API key.

Comment: This is all happening in inappbrowser of Cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it after a lot of search. 
We have to use the API key from Google console rather than what firebase gives. I didn't come across any official advice as such from Google or firebase.